# on editing inserting a new row instead of updating the current row in cakephp 2x

Tags: cakephp, edit

I m having trouble in updating the student profile form,after i gave the       user_id to the student profile.Every time when i try to edit the form, on saving it provide new id to the existing user. I don't know where I'm getting wrong. Plz help.Thanks in Advance.
 Here is my add and edit function in Student Profiles controller:

```
 public function add() {
   if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      $this->StudentProfile->create();
    $data = $this->request->data;
     $data['StudentProfile']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
     // code implemented below               
     //$this->loadModel('User');

      if ($this->StudentProfile->save($data)) {
        //Update user here if Profile saved successfully 
        //$this->StudentProfile->id = $this->Auth->user('id');

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your account profile has been   created'));
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'studentprofiles',   'action' => 'index'));
        }else{
             $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Profile was saved, but an  error has occurred while updating the Users table'));
            //Email your self the user ID here or something ??
        }
    } 
     $h=array(

  'fields' => array('Height.height'),
  'recrusive' => 0
);

    $this->loadModel('Height');
    $height = $this->Height->find('list',$h);
    $this->set(compact('height'));
}

public function edit($id = null) {
      if (!$this->StudentProfile->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid student profile'));
      }
     if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        $this->request->data['StudentProfile']['user_id'] = $this->Auth- >user('id');
      // code implemented below               
     // $this->loadModel('User');
        if ($this->StudentProfile->save($this->request->data)) {
            //$this->StudentProfile->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The student profile has been   saved.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The student profile could not be   saved. Please, try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('StudentProfile.' . $this-  >StudentProfile->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->StudentProfile->find('first',   $options);
    }
      $h=array(

  'fields' => array('Height.height'),
  'recrusive' => 0
);

    $this->loadModel('Height');
    $height = $this->Height->find('list',$h);
    $this->set(compact('height'));
 }
```

Comment: Are you specifically trying to reset the value in **user_id** every time you save that form? Will the associated user ever change or do you only need to save it when the record is first added?

Comment: no McWayWeb, user_id will stay same,the problem was with student profile id ,it was giving the existing student profile a new id on edit. but now it resolved as below ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe I'm replying to my own question . Well In case anyone have the same above problem,the solution is just add the following code after this-

```
 $this->request->data['StudentProfile']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
 // add this code to avoiding giving new id to existing user on edit:
        $this->request->data['StudentProfile']['id'] = $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way of saving edited information is to set the ID on the model before the save like so

```
$this->StudentProfile->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

If you initiate a save after setting the above then the row will be edited and not add a new row.